# Implementing swiping between different views

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've been updating an Android app today which so far had a single `TableLayout`-based `View`. Now, I'd like to duplicate that `View` with another set of backing data, and use horizontal swiping to switch between both. At some point I'd also like to add a third "page" with a different TableLayout.

I haven't really found any good ways to get this going. I've been looking at http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html, and I actually copied the code fragment for the Tabs Pattern with `NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`. That results in a little dropdown widget being added to the `View` title in the action bar, but clicking it doesn't show the tabs I set up (with `actionBar.addTab()`). I'm also not sure how to set up the view (XML) code to stick the `TableLayout`s in there.

I should mention that I don't have to care for pre-4.0 Android for this, so compatibility is not (much of) an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the other answers ended up helping much. However, this one is pretty good:

http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/

Answer (score 1):

Try to Use ViewPager Widget you can find useful links on the web, this widget handle the horizontal swiping between views.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537#

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't really found any good ways to get this going.

Try `ViewPager`. Here is an Android Developers Blog post on `ViewPager`: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Here is a small sample app using `ViewPager`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Fragments